# How to display edit button in KendoUI grid on specific lines depending on data

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I use KendoUI in my asp.net app to display a grid.

I want the user to be able to edit the lines depending of the state of each line.

The grid looks like this :

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<UIMuModel>()
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
        columns.Select().Width("50px");
        columns.Bound(c => c.Name).Width("120px");
        columns.Bound(c => c.State).Width("120px");
        if (Model.AllowEdit)
        {
            columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); });
        }
})            
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
```

I am able to enable or disable the edit command for the whole grid, but I don't know how to do it on a per-line basis : only display the edit button on this line if the `State` is "open"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution :

I have a javascript function, with the model as parameter, and returns a boolean, to define if the line can be edited or not :

```
function isLineEditable(model) {
    return model.State === "open";
}
```

And on the command definition, we can set a javascript function to call, to set if the button is visible :

```
columns.Command(command => { command.Edit().Visible("isLineEditable"); });
```

Comment: This is definitely easier. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this on the client side after the data gets bound. Firstly, create a dataBound handler:

```
<script>        
      function dataBound(e) {
           var grid = this;

           grid.tbody.find("tr[role='row']").each(function () {
               var model = grid.dataItem(this);

               if (!model.AllowEdit) {
                   $(this).find(".k-grid-edit").addClass("k-state-disabled");
               }
           });
       }
</script>
```

...and then add this event handler to your widget:

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<UIMuModel>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Select().Width("50px");
        columns.Bound(c => c.Name).Width("120px");
        columns.Bound(c => c.State).Width("120px");
        if (Model.AllowEdit)
        {
            columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); });
        }
    })            
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .Events(e => e.DataBound("dataBound"))
```

Comment: I found an easier way to do it, but I still upvote your answer because it works, and it allows more customisation than mine